# Inconsistent output from c++ multithreaded program

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have the following program in C++:

```
// multithreading01.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <process.h>

using namespace std;

bool threadFinished = false;

struct params {

    string aFile;
    bool tf;

};

void WriteToFile(void *p)
{
    params* a = (params*)p;
    cout<<a->aFile<<endl;
    a->tf = true;
    _endthread();
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    params *param01 = new params;
    params *param02 = new params;

    param01->aFile = "hello from p1";
    param01->tf = false;
    param02->aFile = "hello from p2";
    param02->tf = false;

    _beginthread(WriteToFile,0,(void *) param01);
    _beginthread(WriteToFile,0,(void *) param02);

    while(!param01->tf || !param02->tf)
    {

    }
    cout << "Main ends" << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

However, I am getting inconsistent outputs such as

output 1:

hello from p1
hello from p2

output 2:

hello from p1hello from p2

output 3:

hhello from p2ello from p1

How can I get a consistent output from this code? I am using Visual C++ 6.0 Standard Edition.

Comment: You will not have consistent output with independent threads.  The output is happening ... asynchronously, as is the whole point of an independent thread.

Comment: If you want consistent output, run all of the code within a single thread (i.e. don't spawn any threads).  The threads will, by their nature, run at unpredictable times relative to each other, which means their outputs will occur in various orders relative to each other.

Comment: Or, if you must use threads, you'll need some sort of synchronization mechanism. A semaphore or condition variable might be your best bet here.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using the `std::thread` tools?

Comment: @kfsone because he's using VC++ 6.0... that thing was released in the late 90s IIRC... EDIT: I actually have a copy as well. Not seeing the release date on the box, but there is something about a $50 rebate I did _not_ claim before Dec 31 2000, and there are warnings about Y2K bugs. EDIT2: copyright is 1998.

Comment: I want to write two files simultaneously, therefore I dont want any conflicts in using the shared resource, is there away to lock it?

Comment: You can simultaneously write to two different files in different threads.  You cannot simultaneously write to the _same_ file in two different threads.

Comment: Oh sure you can . You'll have to mutex lock the snot out of it and probably lose the advantage of multi threading, but you can do it. How how do you mutex lock? Easy peasy in modern C++. Old C++ you'll have to use OS-specific code, but seeing as the IDE is VS 6, the target platform's pretty easy to guess. [Give CriticalSections a read-up](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/windows/desktop/ms682530(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Read this [small writeup](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/176169/can-you-explain-why-multiple-threads-need-locks-on-a-single-core-cpu)

Like everyone mentioned in the comment, when you create threads, generally speaking, idea is to separate tasks and thusly increasing performance on modern multicore architecture CPUs which could one thread per core.

If you want to access same resource (same file in your case) from two different threads then you need to make sure that simultaneous access from two threads doesnt happen otherwise you would see the problem that you are seeing.

Your provide safe simultaneous access by protecting shared resource using some locks (e.g [POSIX locks](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/pthread_mutex_lock.html) or you could chose your platform specific lock implementation).

Common mistake beginners do is that they lock the "code" not "resource".

Dont do this:

```
void WriteToFile(void *p)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(var); //for example only
    params* a = (params*)p;
    cout<<a->aFile<<endl;
    a->tf = true;
    _endthread();
    pthread_mutex_unlock(var); //for example only
}
```

You should instead put a lock in your resource

```
struct params {
    lock_t lock; //for example only not actual code
    string aFile;
    bool tf;    
};

void WriteToFile(void *p)
{
    params* a = (params*)p;
    pthread_mutex_lock(a->lock); //Locking params here not the whole code.
    cout<<a->aFile<<endl;
    a->tf = true;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(a->lock); //Unlocking params
    _endthread();
}
```

Comment: You don't use a->lock in the second example, and you lock twice?

Comment: Should `var` be `&a->lock` in the second example, too?